# How can I call up responses from a button? HTML & Javascript

Tags: html, javascript

I am trying to figure out how to how to call back which button a person pressed without using my inefficient method of multiple functions.  The code is below.  I tested it out and this works for what I made it for, but I want to know if there is a more efficient method for doing it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Google Forms 3 -- Ben Klemp</title>

<script>
function inputButton() {
    var input, text;
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    if (input.length <= 0) {
        alert("You must type your name here.");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("question1").hidden = "";
        document.getElementById("inputButton").hidden = "hidden";
        document.getElementById("initialQuestion").hidden = "hidden";
    };
};
function submit() {
    document.getElementById("question1").hidden = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("review").hidden = "";
    document.getElementById("responses1").innerHTML = "What is your name: " + document.getElementById("input").value;
};
function submit1() {
    document.getElementById("responses2").innerHTML = "Do you play video games: Yes"
};
function submit2() {
    document.getElementById("responses2").innerHTML = "Do you play video games: No"
};
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div><!--Heading and Initial Question-->
    <h1>Ben Klemp's Survey</h1>
    <div id="initialQuestion">
        <h3>What is your name?</h3>
        <input type="character" id="input">Type Name Here</input>
        <button type="button" id="inputButton" onclick="inputButton()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="question1" hidden="hidden"><!--Question 1-->
    <h3>Do you play video games?</h3>
    <div id="questionButtons1">
        <button type="button" id="submit1" onclick="submit() + submit1()">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" id="submit2" onclick="submit() + submit2()">No</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="review" hidden="hidden">
<h2>Here are your responses:</h2>
<p id="responses1"></p>
<p id="responses2"></p>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Normally programming questions belong on [SO], but in this case you should try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as your question is asking about working code.

Comment: Code Review Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code. We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide by taking working code and making it better.

If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…

    Best practices and design pattern usage,
    Security issues,
    **Performance**,
    Correctness in unanticipated cases, then you are in the right place!

Comment: You can flag your question (in need of moderator intervention) and ask a moderator to migrate it.

Comment: determining what button was clicked.  ("call up responses" which you wrote in your title, is nonsense). This is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291017/how-to-get-id-of-button-user-just-clicked   One answerw has it for jquery but the other has  it for pure javascript.  Another way is   You could I suppose also pass as a parameter, the id of the button that was clicked, to the function.

Comment: My apologies, barlop.  I probably should have thought about that a little more.  I will try to make an edit to the code so it stores which button was pressed as a variable for later reference in the code.  (Which, by the way, is what I meant by "call up responses".)